# VBA remove comma

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Removecomma()


        Range("R2:R100").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

I am trying to remove all comma in Column R, but this code is not working, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  *"not working"* is a useless error description.

Also `R2:R100` refers not to column R but only to row 2 to 100 in column R therefore the replace method will only apply to rows 2 to 100 in column R. So if you want to apply the replacement to the entire column R you need either to use `Range("R:R")` or `Columns("R")`.
Also I highly recommend to specify in which worksheet this range or column is. Otherwise Excel guesses and it might guess wrong: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R:R")…`

Finally you set `LookAt:=xlWhole` that means the **whole** cell content has to be a comma (and nothing else in it) to be replaced with a space `Replacement:=" "`.

Check out the documentation of the [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) to choose the correct value for the `LookAt:=` parameter ([XlLookAt enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat)).

Note that this code still does not *remove* the comma but replace the comma with a space. To remove it you must change `Replacement:=" "` into `Replacement:=""`.